# How To Make A Set Of Circle CAShapeLayer From A Loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, cashapelayer, cgpoint

```
for (NSValue * point in points){
    CGPoint p = point.CGPointValue;
    CAShapeLayer *point = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [point setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(p.x, p.y, 100, 100)] CGPath]];
    [point setStrokeColor:nil];
    [point setFillColor: [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];
    [point setZPosition:2];
    [self.layer addSublayer:point];
}
```

So I have this code, the points is a NSMutableArray that contains NSValue of CGPoints, however I'm always encountering this error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x7faf214a1a50> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there anyway I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when you deal with a mutable array sync in two different threads.
This is a sync problem.
Copy the points array may slove your problem.
Just modify your code as below:

```
for (NSValue * point in points.copy){
    CGPoint p = point.CGPointValue;
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    [shapeLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(p.x, p.y, 100, 100)] CGPath]];
    [shapeLayer setStrokeColor:nil];
    [shapeLayer setFillColor: [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];
    [shapeLayer setZPosition:2];
    [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the issue :(, but when I tried commenting the [self.layer addSublayer:point]; it was working but I am not able to show the CAShapeLayers.. :(